# How to read codesign information using code

Tags: objective-c, code-signing

I want to verify the code signature of one file, and i can use codesign -dv to get the information from command line.

```
Executable=/Users/user/XXXXXXXX.txt
Identifier=com.apple.xxxxxx
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=281 flags=0x200(kill) hashes=4+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=ca2c3d47e597a19d7776e248832169488bc8c4a0
Signature size=4169
Authority=Apple Mac OS Application Signing
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Info.plist entries=31
TeamIdentifier=K36BKF7T3D
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=8 files=151
Internal requirements count=1 size=128
```

But is there any way to get the same information using code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The source code for the `codesign` tool is available on http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-55202/src/.